# Jquery: How to get the siblings with css property set to display none

Tags: jquery, css, siblings

HI ,

```
<ul>
<li id=tab1 style="display:none;">tab1</li>
<li id=tab2 style="display:block;">tab2</li>
<li id=tab3 style="display:block;">tab3</li>
<li id=tab4 style="display:block;">tab4</li>
<li id=tab5 style="display:block;">tab5</li>
<li id=tab6 style="display:none;">tab6</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get siblings of tab5 with css property display none, how can i get it

```
$('#tab5').siblings().is(':visible');
```

is not working , Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#tab5').siblings(":hidden");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , and i need to do change css to  display block which is closet to tab5